# Google pagespeed-insights API screenshot resolution

Tags: php, screenshot, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

Google's pagespeed-insights API provided screenshots seem to be in small resolution. How can i change the resolution in PHP

```
if($apc_is_loaded) {
                apc_fetch("thumbnail:".$url, $use_cache);
        }
        if(!$use_cache) {
            $screen_shot_json_data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=$url&screenshot=true");
            $screen_shot_result = json_decode($screen_shot_json_data, true);
            $screen_shot = $screen_shot_result['screenshot']['data'];
            if($apc_is_loaded) {
                apc_add("thumbnail:".$url, $screen_shot, 2400);
            }
        }
        $screen_shot = str_replace(array('_','-'), array('/', '+'), $screen_shot);
        $screen_shot_image = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,".$screen_shot."\" class='img-responsive img-thumbnail'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the API (v5) response there is key "final-screenshot", so you can use the data from this key for better resolution
> [Please check this link](https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://developers.google.com&screenshot=true)